# Apache VitualHost Proxy to Non-Stardard URL

Tags: apache-2.2

I have Apache2.2 and want to configure a virtual host such that a subdomain request gets content from a non-standard URL (site on another server), without rewriting the URL shown to the client in the browser. I want "sub.domain.com" to look and behave like "another.domain2.net:100/some/thing". Thus, requesting "sub.domain.com/test.php" should obtain content from "another.domain2.net:100/some/thing/test.php" How do I configure the VirtualHost to do that?

What I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://another.domain2.net:100/some/thing/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://another.domain2.net:100/some/thing/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I request `http://sub.domain.com`, the URL in the browser that fails is shown as `http://sub.domain.com:100/some/thing/`. Looks like it is only replacing the domain name.

Comment: What you're trying to do is called a reverse-proxy. Check the [manual for mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Comment: Yes, I have see that. It fails to display the page, appends :<port>/<url> to URL shown in the browser.

Comment: That config seems mostly correct, in most cases `ProxyPreserveHost` should be switched off though.

Comment: Ah. I switched it off but to no avail. When I request `http://sub.domain.com`, the URL in the browser that fails is shown as `http://sub.domain.com:100/some/thing/`. Looks like it is only replacing the domain name.

Comment: That can have many reasons, what happens when you enter a longer url, e.g. `http://sub.domain.com/index.htm`  or whatever is correct?

Comment: With a long URL, it still fails the same way. I see in the browser: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at http://sub.domain.com:100.`, which I think is valid because the proxying server does not listen on port 100.

Comment: Is `http://another.domain2.net:100/some/thing/` reachable from your browser ? If not, what gives `curl -I http://another.domain2.net:100/some/thing/` from the fron-end server ?

Comment: Yes, in the same browser, `http://another.domain2.net:100/some/thing/` is reachable. I wonder whether this is a case when the URL should be re-written to make it conform?

Answer (score 0):

Why use the proxy for this?

Have you tried mod_rewrite?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

I'm pretty sure it can rewrite the URL as you wish.